# Vertex AI model version using Python SDK

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, mlops

Vertex AI offers a very interesting Model Registry that allows you to store all trained models and track all their versions.

However, I don't manage to create new versions of the same model using the Python SDK. In particular, I have a Vertex AI Pipeline that performs: 1) data preprocessing, 2) feature engineering, 3) feature store creation, and in the end, 4) train a model with AutoML Tabular.

The code of the Pipeline component dedicated to the point 4 is:

```
 automl_training_electric_op = gcc_aip.AutoMLTabularTrainingJobRunOp(
    project=project_bq,
    model_display_name="pred-model",
    display_name="pred-model",
    optimization_prediction_type="classification",
    optimization_objective="maximize-au-prc",
    budget_milli_node_hours=1000,
    dataset=comp5a.outputs["dataset"],
    target_column="fault",
    location=location
)
```

In the Google documentation I didn't find anything that could help me in creating new versions of the "pred-model", in fact, any time I run the pipeline, Vertex AI creates a new model with the same name.

I would like that at each training, AutoML creates a new version of the same model. E.g., v1, v2, v3.

Here, the current situation, in which the same model is replicated and not versioned:
[image]

Comment: Are you perhaps referencing this documentation? https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/model-registry/versioning#new-model-version

Answer (score 2):

[AutoMLTabularTrainingJobRunOp](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/master/components/google-cloud/google_cloud_pipeline_components/aiplatform/automl_training_job/automl_tabular_training_job/component.yaml) was last updated Feb 2, 2022. Meanwhile, support for model versioning was [added](https://github.com/googleapis/python-aiplatform/blob/2073bb3fd39828fd4e0911214f923950aea9a0a9/google/cloud/aiplatform/training_jobs.py#L4590) to the Vertex Python SDK on June 28, 2022. So the issue is that `AutoMLTabularTrainingJobRunOp` needs to be updated to align with what the SDK currently offers, which likely requires a GitHub Issue to be filed.

In the meantime, you can use the Python SDK which does support specifying a version. This can be wrapped in a function-based component to be used in a KFP pipeline.

**Update (2022-10-05):**
The component in the latest release now supports the new parameters related to model versioning: [link](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/google-cloud-pipeline-components-1.0.24/components/google-cloud/google_cloud_pipeline_components/aiplatform/automl_training_job/automl_tabular_training_job/component.yaml)

Comment: I read the link to the GitHub repository. I found a reference to "parent_model" but AutoMLTabularTrainingJobRunOp does not support the model versioning. So basically, at the moment there is not a solution for my problem. In the end, I have to wait that Google updates the SDK to support the versioning. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.